# layout. Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class example.igeniy.MainGamePanel Помогите найти ошибку в разметке

Tags: java, android, imageview, разметка

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="example.igeniy.Menu">


        <view
            class="example.igeniy.MainGamePanel"
            android:id="@+id/surface"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </view>

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Ошибка возникает , когда `imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` во первых появляется ошибка из заголовка вопроса, а во вторых эта строка показана как ссылка на нулевой объект `imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`

```
Объявлено `ImageView imageView1; Bitmap bitmap;` и `imageView1 = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`  `bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.kvadrat);`
```

Я ошибся с выбором лояута ? сам класс у меня на весь экран перерисовывает игровую ситуацию, а поверх класса я хотел в imageview рисовать (передавать с таким же FPS в imageview изображения можно ли часто пользоваться setImageBitmap или придется canvas использовать?).

Comment: 1. Покажите, как у вас определен класс example.igeniy.MainGamePanel

Comment: 2. Покажите, где вы присваиваете imageView1 хоть какое-нибудь значение, прежде чем к нему обращаться?

Comment: спасибо, ваш наводящий вопрос помог ошибку увидеть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я из класса наследуемого AppCompatActivity передаю в setContentView свою разметку в которой объявлен другой класс. Все imageview я должен  объявить в классе который мою разметку отображает, а не в том классе который сам в разметке определен.